# Display border of an element without using border property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a border type look for an element but without using the border property. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `border`?

Comment: I agree with BoltClock, it's always good to state your intention rather than what you believe to be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS3 has two options you could use: `outline` and `box-shadow`.

Or, if you require old browser support, then use a background `div` to create the border.

Comment: `outline` is not new to CSS3.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
<div style="background-color: black; padding: 2px">
    <div style="background-color: white">
         hello!! 
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NxdTW/)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `:before` pseudoelement with a specified `width/height` and a `background-color` applied (of course pseudoelements are not appliable for self-closing elements, like `img`, `input`, `hr`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

use `outline` instead of `border`. This has an extra advantage on it too; the height/width of the div doesn't add the points from the outline, where it does just that with `border`.

Comment: its not supported by all IE, only from IE8

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. However, it's not something I would worry about, since less than 3% of IE users (which is like 0.2% of total/all browser usage) use IE7 or below.

Comment: it's something to worry about if it's in his browser support matrix, and we do not know this.
box-sizing for borders + width:
http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: I have no clue of what you're talking about... what is a 'matrix'? And what does padding and the box model have to do with this?